# Python - Print duplicate dataset in a CSV File (csv.reader)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, reader

I am trying to print out all datasets in a CSV File that exist more than once. Not single values but multiple values together.

So for example:

```
//dataset1: 25,41,1,23,12,//dataset2: 11, 2
//dataset1: 25,41,1,22,13,//dataset2: 11, 2
//dataset1: 25,41,1,23,14,//dataset2: 11, 3
//dataset1: 25,41,1,23,15,//dataset2: 11, 4
//dataset1: 25,41,1,23,15,//dataset2: 11, 5
```

I tried to do this:

```
    with open(str(csv_file)) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            rowset1 = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
            rowset2 = [row[5], row[6]] 
            //this is where I am stuck 
            if rowset1 //exists more than once > 1 or rowset2 //exists more than once > 1:
                print("True")
            else:
                print("False")
```

EDIT:

The output should be:

```
True
True
False
True
True
```

I also tried something like this, but I think this is the wrong approach:

```
len(my_list) != len(set(my_list))
```

Comment: Could you expand the question and show what is the desired output in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

**File**

```
25,41,1,23,12,11,2
25,41,1,22,13,11,2
25,41,1,23,14,11,3
25,41,1,23,15,11,4
25,41,1,23,15,11,5
```

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import contextlib
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':

    res1 = list()
    res2 = list()

    with contextlib.closing(open('file.csv', 'r')) as csv_file:
        reader_orig = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader_orig:
            row_set1 = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
            row_set2 = [row[5], row[6]]

            if row_set1 not in res1:
                res1.append(row_set1)
            else:
                print(row_set1)

            if row_set2 not in res2:
                res2.append(row_set2)
            else:
                print(row_set2)
```

**Output**

```
['11', '2']
['25', '41', '1', '23', '15']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, what is a "dataset" in a CSV? Give an actual excerpt from your CSV, without "//" comments which I presume you added.

Comment: Please add these in comments instead as an answer.

Comment: Like I added, the first 5 values in a row taken together are dataset1 and the other 2 taken together are dataset2. They should be unique so e.g. '25,41,1,23,15' should only exists once in the CSV-File but it exists more than once. I want to check that and then continue.

Comment: I can't yet add comments apparently, not enough "reputation".